# Can I route request based on operation?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an endpoint that accepts two different operations, GET and DELETE.
Can I route requests to the same endpoint to different services based on operation in my dispatch.yaml?

This is how I would like to do in my dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:

  - url: "*/customer/example/uri/"
    operation:GET
    service: aservice

  - url: "*/customer/example/uri/"
    operation:DELETE
    service: anotherservice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `dispatch.yaml` can only route based on url.